# Is $f: \Bbb R \mapsto \Bbb{R^+} =x^2$ Surjective?

Tags: functions

I am pretty sure that $x^2$ is surjective if we go from all reals, to all positive reals. I know that $x^2$ from all reals to all reals is not surjective, but if we only do all reals to positive reals, then all the values of $y$, would also be in the values of $x$, since $y$ cannot be negative.

Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Forget about surjective function, the given example isn't even a function at all.

This is so since in the given example, the element $0$ from the domain, has no image in the codomain.
(Since $0$ doesn't belong to $\Bbb {R^+})$.

---

If you change your codomain from $\Bbb{R^+}$ to $\Bbb {{R_0}^{+}}\; \big(\text{i.e.} ~ \Bbb {R^+} \cup \{0 \}\big)$, then yes, this becomes a surjective function.

Comment: So if I would start from 1 and not zero, it would be surjective?

Comment: @AndroidCoder Take a look at my edit. I have changed my answer, and I think it will answer your question.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. I did not think about 0 not being positive.